# else statement does not return text "ID not found" google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Return works if there is a match but if there is no match, the else statement doesn't work. The whole code is pasted below

```
function doGet(e){
 return getAirportMatch(e) ;
} 
function getAirportMatch(e) {
  
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var regExp  ="^.*"+id+".*|\\s{1}"+id+".*$//gm";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ggLOdIUES107tr_r8R-EAJpbRmZSty8JdXQJfb2U2tU/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lookupRangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
let a = []
  lookupRangeValues.forEach(function (row, i){
     if (row[0].match(regExp))
     {
       
      a.push(lookupRangeValues[i][0]);
       
     }
  });

  if (a)return ContentService.createTextOutput(a).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
  else return ContentService.createTextOutput("ID not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

Comment: When you say "the else statement doesn't work", what do you mean specifically?  Do you get an error message?  What result are you seeing in the case of no match?  Bear in mind that the "if (a)" is only going to get to the "else" if "a" is not a valid object .... it may be that "a" is a valid object, but perhaps is just an empty string / has no content.  You may need to interrogate "a" a little further to determine its status

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: when "a" is not a valid object the else statement should show "ID not found" but it shown blank. Which means that  "else" is not triggering.

Comment: Could you provide your whole function? Is it a WebApp?

Comment: Posted the whole code

Answer (score 1):

### You never enter the `else` statement

**Reason:**

Even if `a` is empty, it is still defined and thus the condition `if (a)` is always fullfilled.

You can verify this easily my modifying your text output and / or implementing logs.

**Sample:**

```js
function getAirportMatch(e) {
  
  ...
  let a = []
  lookupRangeValues.forEach(function (row, i){
    if (row[0].toString().match(regExp))
    {      
      a.push(lookupRangeValues[i][0]);      
    }
  });
  console.log("a: " + a);
  console.log("a.length: " + a.length);
  if (a){
  console.log("if (a)")
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("a is : " + a).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
  }
  else {
  console.log("else (a)")
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ID not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

If the conditonal statement shall only evaluate to `true` for not empty `a`, rewrite the if condition as

`if (a.length > 0)`